# How to insert variable in `validationSchema` Formik and Yup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, yup

I try to validate `<FieldArray />` in Formik with Yup. I generate a bunch of user names after click on "add user". Every Field looks like:

```
<Field
   type="text"
   name={`users.${index}.name`}
/>
<ErrorMessage
   name={`users.${index}.name`}
   component="div"
   className="invalid-feedback"
/>
```

How should my `validationSchema` look like? In my opinion I should add index to `shape` method instead of  simple name. But how can I do this?

```
validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
   // ?????
   name: yup.string().required('First Name is required'),
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

What you want to do is to update the `Formik` component when your initial values changes. set [enableReinitialize](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean) to true

---

You can do 2 things:

1. Append new key/val pair to object like this

```
var eatables = {vegetable: 'Carrot'}
var fruit_var = 'fruit'
eatables[fruit_var] = 'Apple'
console.log(eatables) // {fruit: 'Apple', vegetable: 'Carrot'}
```

2. In ES6, you can use shorthand computed property names.

```
var fruit_var = 'fruit'
var eatables = {[fruit_var]: 'Apple', vegetable: 'Carrot'}
console.log(eatables) // {fruit: 'Apple', vegetable: 'Carrot'}
```

Source - [Javascript: Computed Property Names (ES6)](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-object-creation-356e504173a8)